# Displaying part of commandcolumn based on role

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, webforms, asp.net-membership

I have a page with a gridview. The gridview has "Enable Editing" and "Enable Deleting" checked by default. I want to be able to "uncheck" either of these in the code-behind page_load event.

I found [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5128043/displaying-edit-button-in-gridview-based-on-role) but this hides the whole commandcolumn. I only want to hide the "Edit" or "Delete" hyperlink based on the role of a user. How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to your GridView:  ondatabound="GridView1_DataBound"
Separate the Command Columns in the GridView

```
<asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="True"  />
<asp:CommandField  ShowEditButton="True" />

protected void GridView1_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        if (User.IsInRole("Administrator"))
        {
            GridView1.Columns[0].Visible = true; 
            GridView1.Columns[1].Visible = true; 
        }
        else {
            GridView1.Columns[0].Visible = false;
        }
}
```

Change the column index based on your requirements, the first column is 0

Comment: Thanks, didn't know I could just split up the commandfields like that.

Comment: The User check can be moved to a utility class to avoid hard coding roles on every page.