# How to change the name of AutoGenerated Edit button on GridView Programatically

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I want to rename the Edit & Delete buttons of my gridview in codebehind.
I didn't statically created the buttons from the Design view, they were created programatically in code behind file like this:

```
gw.AutoGenerateEditButton = true; 
gw.AutoGenerateDeleteButton = true;
```

There is no < TemplateField > neither any < ButtonField > in my GridView.
How can I change the name of my Edit and Delete buttons from the code behind?

Comment: You could probably get to them I'm the prerender event.

Comment: Is there any particular reason you are not editing the gridview to declare the buttons?

Comment: @BrianP: The Edit and Delete buttons on my grid should not be displayed every time. It should only be displayed when any user having admin rights with Edit/Delete Flag (Command) wants to access it. That's why i didn't declare the gridview buttons statically

Comment: @sohaiby you can hide the column in page load based on roles http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5128043/displaying-edit-button-in-gridview-based-on-role

Comment: @Deni What are your globalization concerns? You can still set values based on resources...